# Group based on spaces

Tags: python, grouping, whitespace

How can I change this text in Python?

Convert this

```
                    Main1
                    [SPACE]Submain1
                    [SPACE]Submain2
                    [SPACE]Submain3
                    [SPACE][SPACE]Submain3-1
                    [SPACE][SPACE]Submain3-2
```

To this

```
                    Main1
                    Main1;Submain1
                    Main1;Submain2
                    Main1;Submain3
                    Main1;Submain3;Submain3-1
                    Main1;Submain3;Submain3-2
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you, I solved and edit the first message.

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark your answer as accepted to show that the problem is solved. You shouldn't post answers in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I edited message and used answer section as you mention. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this function. Function includes maximum space number (deep) and step. Based on above output maximum space number is 2 and step 1.

```
def spacegroup(listname,deep,deepstep):
    while deep>deepstep-1:
        temphosts0=listname[:]
        for i in range(len(listname)):
            for j in range(1,len(listname)):
                if listname[i][:deep]==' '*deep and listname[i-j][deep-deepstep]!=' ':
                    temphosts0[i]=listname[i-j].rstrip()+';'+listname[i]
                    break
        listname=temphosts0[:]
        deep-=deepstep
    return temphosts0

hosts0 = open('a','r').readlines()
print ''.join(spacegroup(hosts0,2,1)).replace(' ','')
```